# ORM in Coldfusion, existing cfqueries

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion

I'm working on a site built with Coldfusion (cfquery tags and stored procedures).

I'm considering learning / moving the site over to ORM, but I was wondering how involved / complicated this would be.

For example, can I build new pages going forward using ORM to retrieve my data, and then slowly convert my older pages to ORM?

Or does turning on ORM break the queries and stored procedures currently being used on my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you may "build new pages going forward using ORM to retrieve (your) data, and then slowly convert (your) older pages to ORM?"

For complex query, keep using what you had, ORM will not help you much.

Without doing full OO, you can use ORM to help you do CRUD without coding a line of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Henry's answer is a good 'un, but one question occurs to me: if you have an already working site, why would you mess with it to convert it to using Hibernate?  What's the benefit you're perceiving here?  I'm not saying there isn't one (~ at all.  I don't mean to suggest there is no good reason: this is not a loaded question), but I would be hesitant to mess with a site's working code without good reason.

And if you do decide to make the change, I would heavily load test the "before" and "after" change.

Comment: Well I was thinking that a slow conversion to ORM would make it easier to update / change going forward...plus easier for new programmers to maintain.